# Django, Openpyxl: column widths are returning strange values

Tags: python, django, width, openpyxl

inside my app I'm creating a simple workbook and -sheet! Afterwards I'm iterating through a dictionary to adjust the columns width and the rows height.

**functions.py**

```
def create_workbook():
    dict_col_width = {
        'A': 2.22, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 2.33, 'D': 2.89,
    }
    dict_row_height = {
        1: 44.4, 2: 9.9, 3: 15.6, 4: 85.2,
    }

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Some title"

    for key, value in dict_col_width.items():
        ws.column_dimensions[key].width = value

    for key, value in dict_row_height.items():
        ws.row_dimensions[key].height = value

    return wb
```

**views.py**

```
...
wb = create_workbook()
file_text = "some_file_name"
response = HttpResponse(content=save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={file_text}.xlsx'

return response
```

My problem is, that after downloading and opening the file, it seems the column widths have been created randomly. I've also tested the column width with the numbers 1 to 4 and these were the results:

- ws.column_dimensions[...].width = 1 --> results in a width of 0.56
- ws.column_dimensions[...].width = 2 --> results in a width of 1.22
- ws.column_dimensions[...].width = 3 --> results in a width of 2.22
- ws.column_dimensions[...].width = 4 --> results in a width of 3.22

Strangely enough the rows were working perfectly fine! I've adjusted the column width in other programs before and this error(?) never occurred before! Does someone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help and have a great day!

Comment: Widths are actually calculated using some fairly arcane font metrics. Excel approximates these to more common metrics in the GUI, which will vary by OS and is very confusing.

Comment: That's good to know! Thank you!